# variable (height) specified in CSS but not showing in JS

Tags: javascript, variables

I have the following code (taken from Wes Bos). Although the height of the element is specified in CSS it does not appear when I try to access it from JS. When I write *console.log(bar.style.height)* it returns *empty string* (see code below). I tried to look at other ways to access this value without success. The only way I found was to explicitly set it in JS. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this issue ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Video Speed Scrubber</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <video class="flex" width="765" height="430" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" loop controls></video>
    <div class="speed">
      <div class="speed-bar">1×</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <style>
    body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #4C4C4C url('https://unsplash.it/1500/900?image=1021');
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 850px;
  display: flex;
}

video {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.speed {
  background: #efefef;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.speed-bar {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-170deg, #2376ae 0%, #c16ecf 100%);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2px;
  color: white;
  height: 16.3%;
}

  </style>
<script>
  const speed = document.querySelector('.speed');
  const bar = speed.querySelector('.speed-bar');
  const video = document.querySelector('.flex');

  console.log(bar.style.height);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `window.getComputedStyle(bar)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`style` presents the inline style for the selected element

if you want to get CSS value, you need to get the computed style, using [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

> The `Window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, ***after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain***

```js
const speed = document.querySelector('.speed');
const bar = speed.querySelector('.speed-bar');
const video = document.querySelector('.flex');

console.log(getComputedStyle(bar).height);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Video Speed Scrubber</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
      background: #4C4C4C url('https://unsplash.it/1500/900?image=1021');
      background-size: cover;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      width: 850px;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    video {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    
    .speed {
      background: #efefef;
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
      margin: 10px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .speed-bar {
      width: 100%;
      background: linear-gradient(-170deg, #2376ae 0%, #c16ecf 100%);
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 2px;
      color: white;
      height: 16.3%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <video class="flex" width="765" height="430" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" loop controls></video>
    <div class="speed">
      <div class="speed-bar">1×</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But the result is in px, right? So, how do we get the original input value (= 16.3%)?

Comment: @hisam as noted in the doc, *The values returned by getComputedStyle are resolved values ... values includes the resolution of percentages ... will be replaced by their pixel equivalent*

Comment: I see. Thank you.